# Convert PowerPoint file to ODP format?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, ms-office

Is there any way in `.Net` to convert an MS Office Powerpoint .PPT to .ODP?

I've searched the web, and I only see so-called online converters. I've ony found one commercial option, Aspose, which starts at $500.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built in. You're looking at a third party library.

One option I know can work and is fairly easy to do is [unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv). It's just a command line script you can call. The problem is that you take on a lot of dependencies. You need Open Office installed, and the script is in python so you need that available, too.

Comment: Is having OpenOffice installed a requirement for using unoconv?

Comment: Yes, it's required.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free online converter like [alterapps.com](http://alterapps.com) , This works for me all the time. quick and efficient.